# Xamarin.Forms: Map.IsShowingUser not showing current location?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

This is the `xaml` for the app I'm working on. It simply displays a map on the screen with a `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GasStations"
             x:Class="GasStations.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="200"
            x:Name="MyMap"
            IsShowingUser="true"/>
            <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets">
                <ListView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>dog</x:String>
                        <x:String>cat</x:String>
                        <x:String>bird</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </ListView.ItemsSource>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I set the property `Map.IsShowingUser="true"` thinking that it would display the current location, but it's not showing the point.

This is what the form looks like. It doesn't display the *current location* pin.

My question is: how can I add current location to the map?

[image]

Comment: Touch the "My Location" button (top right)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Geolocation plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) to get your current location. If you don't have it already and then use the MoveCamera method to move to that position:

```
private async Task TrackCurrentLocation()
{
var current = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();
current.Accuracy = 30;
float bearing =//bearing in case any
var pins = new Pin { Label = "ME", Icon =''yourIcon"), Flat = true 
};
var latitude = current.Latitude;
var longitude = current.Longitude;

Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    pins.Position = new Position(latitude, longitude);
    pins.Rotation = bearing;
    if (MapTrack.Pins.Count == 0)
    {
        MapTrack.Pins.Add(pins);
    }
    else
    {
        MapTrack.Pins[0] = pins;
    }
    MapTrack.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewPosition(new Position(latitude, longitude)));
});
}
```